# How to show an alert everytime date range picker dialog is opened?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I am trying to implement the [date range picker](https://www.daterangepicker.com/#example5) in my web project. I have followed all the steps described in the documentation:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"> </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />

<input type="text" name="datefilter" value="" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        $('input[name="datefilter"]').daterangepicker({
             autoUpdateInput: false,
             locale: {
                 cancelLabel: 'Clear'
             }
        });

        $('input[name="datefilter"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
             $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY') + ' - ' + 
             picker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
        });

        $('input[name="datefilter"]').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
            $(this).val('');
        });
    });
</script>
```

- Now I want to show an `alert("You have opened datepicker")` everytime the `date range picker` dialog shows. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `show.daterangepicker` [event](https://www.daterangepicker.com/#events) for displaying alert. Here is a working code. I have added a function for displaying alert on `show.daterangepicker` event. I have used `setTimeout` so that the alert does not block the UI before the dropdown comes out.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />

<input type="text" name="datefilter" value="" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        $('input[name="datefilter"]').daterangepicker({
             autoUpdateInput: false,
             locale: {
                 cancelLabel: 'Clear'
             }
        });

        $('input[name="datefilter"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
             $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY') + ' - ' + 
             picker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
        });

        $('input[name="datefilter"]').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
            $(this).val(''); 
        });
        
        $('input[name="datefilter"]').on('show.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                alert("You have opened datepicker");
            }, 0);
        });
        
    });
</script>
```